# rankFD() returning Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, anova

I'm conducting an experiment with have the following data:

[image]

I'm trying to run a non-parametric Anova-Type Statistic test. However, I keep getting this error:

```
rankFD(Tardiness~Jobs*Stages*ShopCondition*PD*CV, data = Datos)
Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

rankFD(StdDev~Jobs*Stages*ShopCondition*PD*CV, data = Datos)
Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

I've already adressed the obvious concern of checking if I have any null or infinite values on my data, but it appears that everything is in order according to functions is.na() and is.infinite() (both returning FALSE meaning 0 values in the data are NA or Infinite).

If needed, here is the data set used in the experiment:
[Data sample](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/otavjoebxcy6yvzxncpj2/DataSample.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=ofkgzvr20rjna5emcm4uo20sh)

Can someone help me find where is the mistake in this.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what the issue is for certain, but have you tried stripping the formula back to `Tardiness~Jobs` and then adding one variable at a time and see if you get the same error. I.e. - I can run `rankFD` and get a result just by dropping `*CV` from the end of the formula. Maybe there is only one row of data per group when you add so many factors?

Comment: Thank you so much! This doesn't address the error that I am obtaining but it sure helps with my experiment since I don't plan on using all factors. As a provisonal solution it helps a lot.